# Posting a model and additional parameters from javascript to an MVC3 controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have some JS which is passing (or trying to pass) a model and a string to an MVC controller.

The JS code is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: self.ajaxValidationUrl,
    type: "POST",
    data: { model: $("form").serialize(), stepList: thisStepList },
    async: false,
    success: function(errors) {
        console.log("Errors...");
        if (errors.length > 0) {
            anyServerError = true;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
            console.log(errors[i].ErrorMessage);
            self.errorList += "<li>" + errors[i].ErrorMessage + "</li>";
        }
    }
});
```

The Controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ValidateReport(MyTemplate model, string stepList)
{    
    var errors = model.Validate();
    return Json(errors);
}
```

The model parameter is blank and isn't resolving to the MyTemplate object.  The post parameters are coming in ok.

Comment: can you post the posted values that you can see in the fiddler or firebug? also post the MyTemplate class

Comment: Your problem is probably in the data you are posting. `$("form").serialize()` will serialize your form into post data (`foo=bar&bar=baz`), and then jQuery will serialize that again, since you pass an object as `data`. So you will post something like `model=foo%3Dbar%26bar%3Dbaz&stepList=...`. In what format does the server expect the data? I'm guessing that changing `serialize` to `serializeArray` might do the trick.

Comment: Here's a sample of the response: model ReportId=c86b8427-e249-4384-bc47-5300b2f9e346&UserId=ee733263-8fe3-41a9-b511-7e501e0bf2df&CompanyId=10c5caf6-b50f-4b31-8842-4a257dde9275&ReportName=Test+Now&TimePeriodType=Yesterday
stepList ReportName,ReportList,ReportTypes

Comment: Was you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a JSONmodel binder I got from somewhere, the place has escaped me but look at this.

```
 public class FromJsonAttribute : CustomModelBinderAttribute
    {
        private readonly static JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();



 public override IModelBinder GetBinder()
    {
        return new JsonModelBinder();
    }

    private class JsonModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var stringified = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request[bindingContext.ModelName];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringified))
                return null;
            return serializer.Deserialize(stringified, bindingContext.ModelType);
        }
    }
}
```

That allows you to do this in your controller.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult GiftsCOG([FromJson] List<GiftModel> gifts, [FromJson] string guid)
 {
 }
```

This allows you to pass JSON from javascript.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work.  It didn't like binding a model using this method.

Comment: If you want help getting it to work, I will be happy to help, I find it a nice thing to have in my apps.  Code consolidation.  However if you dont like this method, I wont bother posting anymore details.